# Confusion about SSL certificates on Windows (PFX)

Tags: windows, security, ssl

I'm trying to create a company-internal CA to get rid of all the SSL exceptions needed for our servers, but while creating the certs, I got some doubt about the security implications of doing so.
The way I've understood how this needs to be done is:

- Create self-signed cert with CA flag (openssl gives me a .pem and
  .key file) as ca.mycompany.org
- Roll these files into a .pfx
- Install the .pem in the trusted root CA store of our clients' Firefox cert store
- Install the .pfx in the system trusted root CA store of our Windows clients (for IE and Chrome)
- Create certs signed by ca.mycompany.org for all our internal servers

My doubts now come from this: It's not possible to create a valid PFX without a private key - and once a certificate is installed on a PC, everyone can export the PFX from the trust store again. This means, that everyone theoretically has access to the CA private key, and could theoretically issue their own certificates signed by our new internal CA. This would open all doors for rogue servers and other trickery (as the worst attacker often comes from the inside...)

I'm pretty sure my thoughts have taken a wrong turn somewhere, the PFX/SSL concept can't have been designed with such a big fault in it, but I can't seem to find my error. Please provide me with enlightenment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only install the public key of the CA on the clients, the private key should never ever leave the CA computer (except for the backup of course, which should be placed into a safe, ideally in a remote location).

Actually it is common practice to create a sub-ca to generate the actual certificates on a different machine and then turn the root-ca off and turn it only on again to create new certificates to the sub-ca when they expire.

It is much easier to just revoke the sub-ca in case it is compromised.

Comment: This looked like the obvious way to do it securely to me, too, but the OpenSSL tool doesn't allow creating PFX files with a public key, it requires the private key. That's why I'm even asking.

Comment: Then use a different format than pfx.

Comment: PFX is what most guides seem to use...
OpenSSL can't create this Microsoft SST format. I'll see whether PKCS7 works, now...